# How far from the wall should I put the toilet flange?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, installation

I'm installing a new toilet and I'd like to know how far from the back wall I should install the flange.  I think that 12" is recommended, but I see that lot are installed closer. Sometimes as close as 9".

Comment: Rather than guessing or trying to pull some random data off the internet why don't you simply see what is required for the toilet stool that you intend to install????

Comment: I don't understand why this was voted down? It seems like a legitimate question.

Comment: A 12" rough-in will give you the most choice in toilets. If you needed to go to a 10", there are far fewer choices out there. (And the price will go up a bit.) Any other number isn't recommended, due to scarcity.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're installing a whole new flange, use the standard rough-in distance of 12" and get a toilet with a 12" rough-in. If the flange is already there and it's less than 12" away from the wall and you don't want to move it, use whatever toilet will fit or install an offset flange.